# Web to Case- Lightning-Input date/time - Not populated in Case Object

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a web to case using Lightning-Input Date instead of Input tag.  The date/time and ContactEmail is not getting populated into case object whereas all other fields in the form is being populated successfully.

Pls  help me to fix this date /time population. 
Here is the code ,

```
   <legend class="legends"> Event Date / Time </legend> 
     <span >    
    <label class="lb"  for="00N0r000000OAQR" > Date: <abbr class="red">*</abbr> 
    </label>
   <lightning-input class="front-padding"   id="00N0r000000O***" name="00N0r000000O***"  type="date">  </lightning-input>
    </span> <br>
    <span>
       <label class="lb"  for="00N0r000000OAQW" > Start Time: <abbr class="red">*</abbr> </label>
       <lightning-input  class="front-padding"  min="06:00" max="23:00"  id="00N0r000000****" name="00N0r000000****"   type="time" variant="label-hidden" required placeholder="00:00" >   
       </lightning-input>
```

[image]

Comment: how exactly are you attempting to "populate" those fields?  its unclear how you are creating the records

Comment: I am creating the record using web to case - POST method. I can create case with all the fields except these three fields date/time/COntactEmail.

Answer (score 0):

in [summer19 Release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_aura_components.htm) they introduce New Attributes for Aura/LWC input components. you have to use for date `dateStyle` and for time `timeStyle` to get what ever format you want